# Isomorphic colimits have isomorphic objects?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings in characteristic $p$. Let $\phi_{A}:A\rightarrow A,\phi_{B}:B\rightarrow B$ be the Frobenius morphisms, i.e. the $p$-power maps. If we have ${\rm{colim}}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A={\rm{colim}}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B$, where the transition maps are Frobenius morphisms, can we show that $A=B$?

Comment: What is $\lim_\phi C$ for $\phi \colon C \to C$? I never seen this notation.

Comment: @azif00: Ok, it seems that I should ask the question more concretely.

Comment: @ToneyLeung I already saw the question, when the part with category theory was still in it, and started thinking about the following: Do you maybe mean, that given two functors $F,G\colon\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ with $\varinjlim F\cong\varinjlim G$, you have $FI\cong GI$ for every object $I\in\operatorname{Ob}\mathcal{I}$?

Comment: @Samuel Adrian Antz: I ask the converse of this.

Comment: @ToneyLeung Indeed you do, my mistake. I fixed my comment, but this result now is not true in general. Consider for example coproducts, which are special colimits and then for example $\{0;1\}+\{2;3\}\cong\{0\}+\{1;2;3\}$.

Comment: @Samuel Adrian Antz: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you checked any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Also it's a bad idea to use "$=$" when you mean isomorphism.

Recall that an $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra $R$ is *perfect* if the Frobenius map $\varphi : R \ni r \mapsto r^p \in R$ is an isomorphism. The colimit of powers of the Frobenius you describe is the *perfection* of an $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra, and it is named that because it's the left adjoint of the inclusion of perfect $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras into $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras. This makes perfect $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras a [reflective subcategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) of $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras, which among other things implies that perfection fixes any perfect $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra.

This is all abstract context for the following more specific counterexample: take $A = \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, whose perfection is $\mathbb{F}_p[x^{\frac{1}{p^{\infty}}}]$, the ring obtained by adjoining all $p^n$-power roots of $x$. Then take $B = \mathbb{F}_p[x^{\frac{1}{p^{\infty}}}]$ to be the perfection. More generally, we could take $A$ to be any $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra which is not perfect and $B$ to be its perfection.

[These notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/teaching/prismatic-columbia/lecture8-perfections-in-mixed-characteristic.pdf) by Bhatt have a more general claim right before Remark 1.4 about when two algebras have isomorphic perfections but I'm not familiar enough with universal homeomorphisms to say anything about it.

Comment: Most of the cited remark of Bhatt is just a technicality to work around the fact that $x \mapsto x^p$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear but not $k$-linear for general $k$. But as you know, whenever you have a ring homomorphism $A \to B$ then every $B$-algebra becomes an $A$-algebra, and specialising to the case where $B = A$ we end up with a way of twisting $A$-algebra structures.

Comment: @Zhen: ah, I meant the part before Remark 1.4 (I guess I'm not sure whether it's part of Remark 1.3) where he talks about universal homeomorphisms. I've never worked with universal homeomorphisms so I neither know how to verify that claim nor produce a more interesting counterexample from it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I feel as though Bhatt is missing hypotheses there (but maybe not?). In any case, I am familiar with the case wehn $R$ and $S$ (in Bhatt's notation) are what are called 'perfectly of finite type' over $k$. Then, the result can be found as Corollary A.16 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.8519.pdf